# Blur on box alert

Tags: javascript, css, blur

I am making a program, I want to apply the "Blur" effect when an alert box arrives to the whole document.
Could you suggest me how to do it?

I was using an example I found on the web but I don't know if it is correct. I am almost sure that the error is in the JavaScript but I don't know how to correct it.

Thanks for your help.

```js
function addBlur() {
  $(‘#main’).addClass(‘blur’);
  $(‘#t_TreeNav’).addClass(‘blur’);
}
```

```css
.body {
  heigh: 665px;
  background-image: url(https://carontestudio.com/img/caronte-web-estudio-logo.png");
  background-size: 10rem;
}

.blur {
  flex-grow: 1;
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h2>This is a sample paragraph.</h2>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please edit the snippet I've made from your code to remove/correct the typos. I would've done it myself, but I don't know what's intentional for writing here and what's an actual mistake from/in your code. Though @isherwood has taken the liberty of correcting the errors, and removing code (which is normally not advised).

Comment: Take the time to get to know the post editor. There's no need for a bunch of backslashes. Also, your CSS has a typo (`heigh`), some of your closing tags were malformed, and you have invalid quotation marks.

Comment: See any error message?

Comment: @Marc, please don't correct code issues. The invalid quotation marks are a problem that the OP needs to deal with and may be the cause of the actual problem.

Comment: Got it. Realized after I started that there was... too much to do.

Comment: So do you call your function? And it appears you are using something other than an IDE to edit it since you have fancy quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this in vanilla JS with `addEventListener`. You can attach it to [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) like this:

```
document.addEventListener('alert', function() {
  // do something
});
```

You can mix it with jQuery or write it with vanilla JS also:

```
document.addEventListener('alert', function() {
  document.querySelector('#someId').classList.add('blur');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better way of doing this would be to use the Dialog element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

```js
const showButton = document.getElementById('showDialog');
const favDialog = document.getElementById('favDialog');
const confirmBtn = favDialog.querySelector('#confirmBtn');

// "Show the dialog" button opens the <dialog> modally
showButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector("body").classList.add("blur");
  favDialog.showModal();
});
// "Confirm" button of form triggers "close" on dialog because of [method="dialog"]
favDialog.addEventListener('close', () => {
  document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("blur");
});
```

```css
.blur {
  filter: blur(8px);
}

#favDialog {
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

button {
    margin: 15px auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1>
Page Text Header
</h1>

<p>
Etiam iaculis nunc ac metus. Vestibulum eu odio. Quisque libero metus, condimentum nec, tempor a, commodo mollis, magna.

Pellentesque auctor neque nec urna. Etiam rhoncus. Cras non dolor.

Praesent ac massa at ligula laoreet iaculis. Etiam feugiat lorem non metus. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit.

In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Fusce neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

Vestibulum turpis sem, aliquet eget, lobortis pellentesque, rutrum eu, nisl. Nunc nec neque. Morbi ac felis.
</p>

<dialog id="favDialog">
  <form method="dialog">
    <div>
      <span>Button Notification Text</span><br/>
      <button id="confirmBtn" value="default">Ok</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</dialog>
<button id="showDialog">Show the dialog</button>
```